# Trying to install scad-mode from package repository

Tags: package-repositories

[This melpa.org page](https://melpa.org/#/scad-mode) suggests that the scad-mode package is installable from a package repository. But I tried adding http://marmalade-repo.org/ to my package archives, but `scad-mode` still doesn't show up in list-packages. Is this page incorrect? I now have

```
'(package-archives                                                                                                                        
   (quote                                                                                                                                  
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")                                                                                             
     ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")                                                                                
     ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages"))))
```

in my `custom-set-variables` list.

And in the description, isn't the correct syntax `M-x package-intstall, not` M-x install-package`?

Comment: Currently I see that there is SSL certification issue for http://marmalade-repo.org/ maybe this can be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scad-mode is available on MELPA, not MELPA stable. You'll therefore need to set up regular MELPA instead of MELPA stable to install it. You might find this opinion piece about MELPA stable useful: https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/etikbz/speaking_as_a_package_maintainer_please_do_not/

Marmalade is unmaintained at this point. Despite [repeated prodding the admin never bothered making it run again](https://nitter.net/mplscorwin/status/1317580399036477441), so I'd remove it from the package archives variable. It should look like this instead:

```
'(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))))
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. Can I interest you in the unanswered https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/62672/100 ? I thought this should have a straightforward answer.